# sinatra and http PUT

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

suppose i want to use curl to put a file to a webservice this way

```
curl -v --location --upload-file file.txt http://localhost:4567/upload/filename
```

in sinatra i can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

put '/upload/:id' do
   #
   # tbd
   #
end
```

how can i read the streaming file?

more or less i want something like this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php#56985

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795205/streaming-web-uploads-to-socket-with-rack) implies that what you want cannot be done, but I don't yet know enough about this to be sure enough to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Phrogz I just found this: http://groups.google.com/group/rack-devel/msg/600825afa08474d8 - thought you might be interested.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic example is writing it to the currect directory you are running sinatra in with no checking for existing files ... just clobbering them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

put '/upload/:id' do
  File.open(params[:id], 'w+') do |file|
    file.write(request.body.read)
  end
end
```

Also, you can leave off the filename portion in the curl command and it will fill it in for you with the filename. Foe example:

```
curl -v --location --upload-file file.txt http://localhost:4567/upload/
```

will result in writing the file to http://localhost:4567/upload/file.txt

Comment: Does the route block wait to run until the request is finished, or does this allow for streaming the results as they arrive?

Comment: I don't know about the streaming ... I missed that detail

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'ftools'

put '/upload' do
  tempfile = params['file'][:tempfile]
  filename = params['file'][:filename]
  File.mv(tempfile.path,File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))),"public","#{filename}"))
  redirect '/'
end
```

In this way, you does not have to worry about the size of the file, since he's not opened (readed) in memory but just moved from the temp directory to the right location skipping a crucial blocker. In fact, the php code do the same stuff, read the file in 1k chunks and store in a new file, but since the file its the same, its pointless.
To try you can follow the answer of Ben.